# Batch Iterable (Apex CPU time limit exceeded) List<Map<>>

Tags: batch

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my Batch Iterable class. I'm trying to create a List of Maps. I'm passing in an entire Map (accountToNewAndOld) which gets broken up into and added into a List iterable.

One thing I noticed is my batch class works when the size is rather small. A soon as the size of the Map grows to 1000s, I get an System error (see below). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[45]|SDIterable.__sfdc_i()

SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[45]|SDIterable.__sfdc_i()

SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[37]|SDIterable.__sfdc_i()

SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[37]|SDIterable.__sfdc_i()

SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[37]|SDIterable.__sfdc_accountToNewAndOldList()

SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[37]|SDIterable.__sfdc_accountToNewAndOldList()

SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[37]|LIST>>>.size()

SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[37]|LIST>>>.size()

EXCEPTION_THROWN|[EXTERNAL]|System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

```
global class SDIterable 
   implements Iterator<Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>>>, Iterable<Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>>>{ 

    public List<Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>>> accountToNewAndOldList = new List<Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>>>();
    Integer i {get; set;} 

   public SDIterable(Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>> accountToNewAndOld){ 
        Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>> tempAccountToNewOldMap = new Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>>();
        if(!accountToNewAndOld.isEmpty()){
            for(Id acc:accountToNewAndOld.keyset()){        
                accountToNewAndOldList.add(new Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>> {acc => accountToNewAndOld.get(acc)});
            }
        }
       i = 0; 
   }      

   global boolean hasNext(){ 
       if(i >= accountToNewAndOldList.size()) {
           return false; 
       } else {
           return true; 
       }
   }    

   global Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>> next(){ 
       if(i == 500){return null;} 
       i++; 
       return accountToNewAndOldList[i-1]; 
   }

    global Iterator<Map<Id, Map<Id, Set<Id>>>> Iterator()
    {
        return this;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that the CPU time limit is consumed by all the code in the request including the code before this class that builds `accountToNewAndOld`. You may need to re-think your approach and find a way to do a lot less work up front even if that leads to more work in each `execute` call of the `Batchable`.